# Why I randomly encounter this fatal error with apc (in Yii Framework)?

Tags: php, yii, apc

I sometimes run into

```
Fatal error: require() [<a href='function.require'>function.require</a>]: apc_fcntl_lock failed errno:6 in C:\web\yii\framework\web\CWebApplication.php on line 345
```

code context:

```
        else
            $controllerID.='/';
        $className=ucfirst($id).'Controller';
        $classFile=$basePath.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$className.'.php';
        if(is_file($classFile))
        {
            if(!class_exists($className,false))
                require($classFile);  ////////////THIS IS LINE 345
            if(class_exists($className,false) && is_subclass_of($className,'CController'))
            {
                $id[0]=strtolower($id[0]);
                return array(
                    new $className($controllerID.$id,$owner===$this?null:$owner),
                    $this->parseActionParams($route),
                );
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Relative runtime environment:

```
OS:win2k3.
PHP Version 5.3.6 
Server API  CGI/FastCGI

apc:
Version 3.1.8-dev
APC Debugging   Disabled
MMAP Support    Disabled
Locking type    File Locks
Serialization Support   php
Revision    $Revision: 308812 $
Build Date  Mar 1 2011 13:31:44
```

What caused this error? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like an APC issue, which I also encounter from time to time. I can't tell you 100% what's going on, but, while developing you often change, move or overwrite files. APC then seems to loose the inode of the file which is used internally to handle to bytecode-caching.

For me the only way to 'fix' the error is to restart the webserver.

Does this also happen on production systems, where you don't change the sourcecode very often?

Comment: Thanks. Exactly the same symptom as I encountered, hope it won't appear after production.

Comment: @LotusH: what about this error message? Are you still having this problem? I'm asking because I just had the same error message on a site after enabling APC on an IIS server working on Windows Server 2008. I don't really understand, because I also tried it on my own machine with IIS + Windows 7, with the same version of PHP, the same version of MySQL, the same data and the same version of APC - it works without any kind of problems. It's really weird: there are almost the same conditions, and it's OK on Windows 7, but faulty on Windows Server 2008...

Comment: OK, sorry, I have to revoke what I said 2 hours ago. I tested the server, and another site, where phpMyAdmin was installed, displayed the same "Fatal error: Unknown: apc_fcntl_lock failed errno:6 in Unknown on line 0" error message. After disabling APC, everything worked again... but that's not a solution... :\

Answer (score 0):

Seems it's apc's deadlock bug http://www.searchtb.com/2014/02/apc-lock-php-fpm.html I asked one of the apc maintainers about this, he suggested me to use opcache instead of apc.